# Elementary proof that knot complements are path-connected

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, knot-theory

The complement of any (topological) knot is path-connected. More precisely, if $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $S^3$) homeomorphic to $S^1$, then $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus K$ (or $S^3\setminus K$) is path-connected.

This result is often assumed in introductory knot theory texts, and is an immediate consequence of Alexander Duality. I would like to cite this result in a first course in metric and topological spaces, however, so would like to know if a more elementary proof exists. By "elementary", I mean that I would like to avoid:

- Assuming that the knot is tame, and using any results from PL-topology;
- Assuming the knot is smooth, and using results from differential topology;
- Using results from algebraic topology (such as Alexander Duality).

Any hints or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to avoid duality only or any homology altogether? You can prove that $\tilde H_*(S^3\setminus I)=0$ by Mayer--Vietoris and compact supports (keep dividing $I$ into two halves), and then compute $H_*(S^3\setminus S^1)$ by Mayer--Vietoris.

Comment: I would be further interested in knowing if there is a strengthening of this result - that the space of paths disjoint from the knot is dense in the space of paths. Perhaps an elementary proof of connectedness (by somehow building such a path) will immediately imply this.

Comment: I don't see how you could offer an "elementary" proof that does not use the dimension theorem somehow -- you need to know that the knot complement is open and dense in $S^3$.  Without that you would have no hope of proving the complement is connected, and these theorems tend to require singular homology or something equivalently powerful.

Comment: Generalize. Instead of a subset of $\ \mathbb R^3\ $ homeomorphic to $\ S^1\ $ consider an arbitrary compact subset  $\ X\subseteq \mathbb R^3\ $ of dimension 1. Then the complement  $\ \mathbb R^3\setminus X\ $ is path connected; indeed the paths of the complement form a dense subset of all paths in  $\ \mathbb R^3\ $ (one may consult Hurewicz & Wallman, but of course).

Answer (score 17):

A proof may be given along the lines of the proof of the Jordan Curve theorem by Doyle (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/160300/1345)). This uses the fundamental group and a variation on Van Kampen, but not homology. So this probably still won't be satisfying to you, but it doesn't use Alexander duality (which is the normal way to do this).

By removing a point from the knot, we may assume that we have a properly embedded line $L\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^3-L$ is disconnected. Since $L$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}^3-L$ is open, and since it is disconnected, there are disjoint non-empty open subsets $U, V$ such that $U\cup V=\mathbb{R}^3-L$. Now embed $\mathbb{R}^3\subset \mathbb{R}^4$, with coordinates $(x,y,z,w)$, and $w=0$ gives $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^4-L)$ is non-trivial. This requires a [generalization of Van Kampen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem#Van_Kampen.27s_theorem_for_fundamental_groups.5B1.5D) which one can find, for example, in [Peter May's book, Chapter 2.](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf)

One may write $\mathbb{R}^4-L$ as a union of two simply connected open sets whose intersection is disconnected. These are $\{w>0\}\cup (\mathbb{R}^3-L) \times (-1,1)$ and $\{w<0\}\cup (\mathbb{R}^3-L) \times (-1,1)$. The intersection is $(\mathbb{R}^3-L) \times (-1,1)$, which is disconnected.

Then the [generalized Van Kampen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem) implies $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^4-L) \neq 0$. However, just as in Doyle's proof of the Jordan curve theorem, one may find a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^4$ sending $L$ to the $w$-axis, whose complement is simply-connected (move L to its graph by a homeomorphism using the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), then project it to the $w$-axis; this has the same proof as Lemma 5.22 in [Armstrong's book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-1793-8)). This is a contradiction.

**Remark: ** One could use homology instead of fundamental group to carry out this argument, with Mayer-Vietoris replacing generalized Van Kampen.

[image]

Comment: Underlying this beautiful argument is the astonishing fact (for me, at least) that, while $L$ may a priori not be isotopic to a straight line in $\mathbf R^3$, $L\times\{0\}$ is isotopic to a straight line in $\mathbf R^4$.

Comment: @ACL the same argument was used in  “Some topological properties of convex sets” by Klee (1955).

Answer (score 13):

Not an answer to the question, but a hopefully related observation  to complete the proof and explain why the result is not obvious, which is may be of interest for your class. I  would mention that a point in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus K$ may be such that every straight line for it meets $K$, that is, its sight is completely hidden by $K$ from outside the convex envelope of $K$. To make such example, just start from a  sphere-filling curve $\sigma:[0,1]\to\partial B(0,1)$, chosen so that for all $0<t<1$ one has $\sigma(t)\neq\sigma(0)=\sigma (1)$. Then define a simple closed curve $\kappa:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $\kappa(t)=(2-t)\sigma(0)$ for $0\le t\le 1$ and $\kappa(t)=t\sigma(t)$ for $1\le t\le 2$; clearly the radial projection of this curve covers the whole unit sphere.

Comment: Antoine's necklace shows that the topic is far from trivial. However, the given problem is elementary, as elementary as basic topological dimension theory (nothing is needed, no fundamental group, no algebraic topology, ...).

Answer (score 3):

(citations for Włodzimierz's assertions)
Option 1:

Cite Theorem IV (4) from [Hurewicz-Wallman](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1199.html) (p. 48):

$E_n$ [*i.e.* $\mathbb{R}^n$] cannot be separated by a subset of dimension $\le n-2$.  The proof is based on Theorem IV (3) (see below) and some manipulation of rational 3-space in real 3-space, using only things one learns in a first course on general/metric topology.

Option 2:

1. Cite Theorem IV (3) (p. 44), which states that a necessary and sufficient condition that a subset $N$ of $E_n$, be $n$-dimensional is that $N$ contain a non-empty subset which is open in $E_n$.
2. Then an easy consequence is (Corollary 2) (p.46):  Let $U$ be an open set in $E_n$, which is neither empty nor dense,  and let $B$ be the boundary of $U$. Then $\text{dim } B = n – 1$. Apply this to $U$ being the complement of $K$ (assuming that $K$ separates $E_3$.
3. Then argue that a continuous injection $Y$ of the circle $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$  cannot have dimension 2 by citing this [Theorem proved by Hurewicz](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002172461) in 1933:  Suppose $f$ is a closed mapping of a (separable metrizable) space X on a (separable metrizable) space Y and suppose $\text{dim } Y - \text{dim } X = k,\text{ where } k > 0$. Then there is at least one point of $Y$ whose inverse-image contains at least $k + 1$ points.  In particular, dimension-raising maps on separable metric spaces aren't injections.

Comment: One may also say about the same as follows: cube $\ \mathbb I^n\ $ is a Urysohn's Cantor manifold.

Comment: H-W state it exactly thus later in their book (Chapter VI §5 p. 93), as being a consequence of the Chapter IV items.  In any event, you are right that an elementary proof really need not use the fundamental group!

Comment: Thanks David and Włodzimierz! If I had more time I would teach some dimension theory. That result of Hurewicz is very counter-intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

First construct a sequence Kn of tame embeddings of S1 in R3 that converges to K.

Then for any points A, B in S3-K construct a sequence of paths Pn from A to B such that Pn is in the compliment of Kn.

Finally perform these constructions with Pn+1 pointwise so close to Pn that the sequence converges to an embedding P.

P is disjoint from every Kn, and hence disjoint from K, hence S3-K is path connected.