# Analogies between analogies

Tags: soft-question, big-picture

"A mathematician is a person who can find analogies between theorems; a better mathematician is one who can see analogies between proofs and the best mathematician can notice analogies between theories. One can imagine that the ultimate mathematician is one who can see analogies between analogies."

--Stefan Banach

See also here: [Famous mathematical quotes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes)

So, can someone give an example of an analogy between analogies?

Comment: I can suggest a candidate: there is an analogy between number fields and function fields.  There is also analogy between number fields and 3-manifolds.  The analogy between these analogies is _______.

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close.  This question seems a little too far out.

Comment: "Higher category theorists! – Harrison Brown"

Comment: I also voted to close.  I am familiar with the quote and found it apt, but its interpretation is proving to be subjective and not especially enlightening.  

Comment: Alright, you've had your fun, people.  This question should really be closed already.

Comment: A new arxiv-article on drawing analogoes between theories by topos th.: http://de.arxiv.org/abs/1006.3930

Comment: http://xkcd.com/762/

Comment: The users who wanted to close this question must have had an allergy to analogy.

Answer (score 33):

Let me give a very concrete analogy between analogies.

1:2 :: 2:4

is to

p:q :: kp:kq

as

x<sup>2</sup>+2x+1 : 0 :: x : -1

is to

ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c : 0 :: x : (-b +- sqrt(b<sup>2</sup>-4ac))/2a.

And this analogy is called *generalization*.

Comment: Nice one!543210

Comment: Part of the point of my answer is that analogies between analogies needn't be terribly abstract, although perhaps Banach meant to imply that they would be and many people seem to take him that way.

Comment: I am reminded of "Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning" (Vol I Induction and analogy in mathematics)-G.Polya . The OP might find reading it interesting and relevant.

Comment: This is really a nice, elementary and important example, thanks!

Comment: 2nd order analogy might be a more intuitive way to put it?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Maybe it's inappropriate here, but I tried to find out, if ChatGPT-4 was able to understand your analogy of analogies. Interestingly enough, he did, he just didn't come up with the single term *generalization*.
https://chat.openai.com/share/760a7b63-5d97-4702-9f42-bcaf08113040

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Wow! That is amazing.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I asked ChatGPT to give me a single term name for this analogy and he came up with (among others) "generalization".

Comment: This analogy ChatGPT didn't get: https://chat.openai.com/share/6617561d-34c5-4589-bc90-8f002b018a5c

Answer (score 22):

I think the following is nice example. Classical Galois Theory gives an analogy between finite étale $k$-algebras and finite sets with an action of the absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(k)$ of $k$. Classical Theory of Covering Spaces gives an analogy between coverings of a nice topological space $X$ and sets with an action of the fundamental groups $\pi_1(X,x)$. Of course this two analogies can be made pretty precise with the a little use of category theory.

Now the analogy between this analogies is to call both analogies Galois correspondence and to compare $\pi_1(X)$ with $\mathrm{Gal}(k)$, to call certain coverings Galois covering, to compare the universal cover of $X$ with the seperable closure of $k$ and so on.

Tamás Szamuely's  beautiful book "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" gives a lot of details and much more about the connection of these things.

Comment: Thank you, this is really a very beautiful analogy between analogies.

Answer (score 16):

A functor is to an analogy as a natural transformation is to an analogy between analogies.

Does this count?  This is making my head spin a little bit...

Comment: Is that an analogy between analogies of analogies?

Comment: Is it clear that analogies behave well under composition?  

Comment: Is there a category of analogies?

Comment: I guess only weak analogies behave well under composition. And what you mean seems like: most mathematical stuff is 0-cells, analogies are n-cells. At least this is my perspective on "analogies of analogies of ...".

Comment: ChatGPT didn't get this analogy: https://chat.openai.com/share/6617561d-34c5-4589-bc90-8f002b018a5c. But Joel's he did.

Answer (score 12):

It is unfortunate Jan Weidner asked his question -- "Can someone give an example of an analogy between analogies?" -- in such a way that he is unlikely to receive very many insightful responses of the kind offered by Joel David Hamkins and philip314. I don't know how insightful my own response will be, but I can provide a context for the topic of analogy, as I was the contributor who added the quotations by Stefan Banach and Stanislaw M. Ulam to the list of [famous mathematical quotes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes/7193#7193).

It is true that Banach is the original source of the quotation, but I first encountered the topic in Ulam's memoir *Adventures of a Mathematician* (1976; 1991). From there I learned that the University of California Press published a collection of papers by Ulam titled *[Analogies between Analogies: The Mathematical Reports of S.M. Ulam and His Los Alamos Collaborators](http://ark.cdlib.org/ark:/13030/ft9g50091s/)* (1991). The collection includes the paper "On the Notion of Analogy and Complexity in Some Constructive Mathematical Schemata" (1981). Rather than attempting to summarize Ulam's results, I'll simply provide an excerpt from the paper's introduction so that interested readers can investigate the topic on their own:

> Throughout the development of
>   mathematics and with the growth of new
>   concepts and more complicated notions,
>   a cohesive tendency and organic
>   structure have been guided by a
>   feeling of analogy between the old and
>   new ideas.
>
> Historically, problems posed by the
>   development of a new mathematical
>   discipline, which originally was only
>   metamathematical, coalesced into new
>   parts of mathematics itself. One could
>   cite, as obvious examples, the study
>   of transformations of a space as
>   points of a new space of such
>   transformations, and the study of
>   algorithms for solving equations as
>   entities per se (group theory, for
>   instance).
>
> The increasing proliferation of
>   notions in pure mathematics may
>   suggest that the idea of analogy
>   itself is amenable to mathematical
>   discussion. One finds that old and
>   elementary formulations of this idea
>   are, in special cases, present in the
>   definitions of the similarity of
>   geometrical figures, more generally in
>   the equivalence of figures-sets,
>   through the elements of a group of
>   transformations, or, more generally
>   yet, through the identity of proximity
>   of such sets in spaces which encompass
>   them.
>
> Two abstract sets of elements may be
>   felt to be "analogous" if the
>   difference between their cardinalities
>   (in the finite case) is small compared
>   to the cardinalities themselves. Two
>   classes of such sets may be deemed to
>   be analogous if the numbers of sets in
>   the two classes differ by "little" and
>   if the cardinalities of the
>   corresponding sets also do not differ
>   by much. Obviously, one needs to
>   attempt to formulate a quantitative
>   criterion, and it is clear a priori
>   that the notion of analogy will not
>   be, in general, transitive.
>
> In this report we merely want to
>   discuss some of the salient features
>   of analogy and exhibit them on a class
>   of examples where we shall attempt to
>   define it, at first, as proximity in
>   the sense of a metric distance in
>   suitably defined spaces. (Ulam 1991; 514)

Hopefully, Ulam's paper will provide some tools to make the topic of analogy less "far out."

Answer (score 5):

This question was posed [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/11/a_categorical_manifesto.html#c005960) followed by some attempted answers.

Comment: Read Weil's examples and thoughts on analogies (theier seductiveness) in his letter to his sister Simone, written in a French prison.

https://www.ams.org/notices/200503/fea-weil.pdf

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41770/explaining-the-number-field-function-field-analogy

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Final dialgebras : from categories to allegories](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/2291540/9912074.pdf), the authors write that, according to Freyd and Scedrov:

> Allegories are to binary relations between sets as categories are to
>   functions between sets.

Assuming functions between sets can be regarded as analogies between sets, and assuming that relations between sets can also be regarded as analogies between sets, then the above quote is expressing, in a pretty direct way, an analogy between analogies.