# William Thurston's quote?

Tags: reference-request

> Mathematics is not about numbers, equations, computations, or
>   algorithms: it is about understanding.

Is this from Thurston? If yes, where and when it has been said. I've checked "ON PROOF AND PROGRESS IN MATHEMATICS" and it is not there.

Comment: Thurston wrote something quite similar on this very site: https://mathoverflow.net/a/44213/4832  "The product of mathematics is clarity and understanding. Not theorems, by themselves."

Comment: @NateEldredge The quote is wildly attributed to Thurston. I was about to "quote" it in a paper that I failed to find the source.

Comment: [Zeilberger](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/quotes.html) says that it's on page 76 of [*Mathematicians: An Outer View of the Inner World*](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-116) by Mariana Cook.  The book doesn't seem to be in Google Books so you may have to visit a library to confirm.

Comment: @NateEldredge Great. I'll do. Meanwhile, I am not using it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This quote is from the book "Mathematicians: An Outer View of the Inner World" (Mariana Cook and Robert Clifford Gunning, Princeton University Press, 2009).

https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt2jc8h2

"Mathematics is not about numbers, equations, computations, or algorithms: it is about understanding. I’ve loved mathematics all my life, although I often doubted that mathematics would turn out to be my life’s..."

Comment: Thanks :) I am surprised why my search before posting the question didn't lead me to this book.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post this as an answer since it's too long for a comment. Even though it does not directly answer the question, I would like to mention that a related quote appears in a very interesting dialogue between Rota and Sharp in 1985 (https://fas.org/sgp/othergov/doe/lanl/pubs/00326965.pdf):

> ROTA: Mathematics is the study of analogies between analogies. All
>   science is. Scientists always want to show that things that don’t look
>   alike are really the same. That’s one of their innermost Freudian
>   motivations. In fact, that’s what we mean by understanding.
>
> SHARP: You often hear that the purpose of a scientific theory is to
>   predict, That’s not correct. The purpose is understanding. Prediction
>   is one way to test whether our understanding is correct. Simplicity,
>   scope, and beauty are as important as prediction in judging whether a
>   theory leads to understanding.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13832/

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.