# Source of quotation about the waste-baskets of physicists

Tags: reference-request

In an article I'm writing I want to quote (with attribution) the original version of an aphorism that says that one can often find mathematical gold in the waste-baskets of physicists.  Would someone provide a reference to that original version?

Note added after awarding bounty: For the time being, I'm going to assume that the quote is actually due to me!  (I came up with it a few weeks ago, but it leaped into my mind with such rapidity that I suspected I wasn't inventing it so much as remembering it.)  If anyone finds the quote in the next few months (before I include it in my own published work without attribution), please let me know!  I'll be glad to make private arrangements to transfer 50 of my reputation points to you.

Comment: I don't suppose I could interest you in a joke about wastebaskets and philosophers?

Comment: Not what I need (though it's a good one).

Comment: "The advantage is that mathematics is a 
field in which one's blunders tend to show 
very clearly and can be corrected or erased 
with a stroke of the pencil. It is a field 
which has often been compared with chess, 
but differs from the latter in that it is only 
one's best moments that count and not 
one's worst. A single inattention may lose 
a chess game, whereas a single successful 
approach to a problem, among many which 
have been relegated to the wastebasket, 
will make a mathematician's reputation." 
Excerpt from Ex-Prodigy: 
My Childhood and Youth 
by Norbert Wiener, p. 21

Comment: The only (alleged) quotation I recall about a mathematician and a trash can: http://mathoverflow.net/a/7207/22971

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: And what would be the source of the quote about waste-baskets and philosophers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one scientist (not quite a mathematician) who found gold in wastebaskets:

*I started looking in the trash cans of science for such phenomena [fractal scaling], because I suspected that what I was observing was not an exception but perhaps very widespread.*

[Benoit Mandelbrot](http://faculty.cbu.ca/philosophy/arcadia/librar15.htm)

It seems he meant this literally, and at least one paper [1] was inspired by a scrap he grabbed from a wastebasket.

[1] B. Mandelbrot, *Information theory and psycholinguistics: a theory of words frequencies*, in: P. Lazafeld, N. Henry (Eds.), Readings in Mathematical Social Science, MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, 1966.

Comment: Apparently he used both "the trash cans of science" and "a pure mathematician's wastebasket".  A resourceful man.

Comment: I consider Mandelbrot to **be** quite a mathematician.

Comment: I like this answer, and will award it the bounty, since it comes the closest (in meaning) to the quote whose attribution I was seeking.

Comment: Well to *have been* more accurately (R.I.P.)

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat similar quote of Alain Connes "The mathematical concepts that arise naturally in physics often turn out to be fundamental, as Hadamard pointed
out" can be found in "The Princeton Companion to Mathematics" http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html page 1006 (Article VIII-6).

I searched in the Hadamard's "An Essay on the Psychology of Invention in the Mathematical Field" https://archive.org/details/eassayonthepsych006281mbp for the mathematical gold in the waste-baskets of physicists but have found nothing.

P.S. Dyson's "Missed opportunities" can be found here http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183533964 However it does not contain your quote.

**Note added: I just found a remotеly similar quote "On the fringes of physics it contains such recent mathematical gems as Virasoro algebra representations on the moduli spaces of curves" in Yuri Мanin's essay "Interrelations between Mathematics and Physics" http://www.emis.de/journals/SC/1998/3/pdf/smf_sem-cong_3_157-168.pdf His other essays can be found in the book http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=cworks-20 I have not checked it for the searched quote (I doubt it can be found there).**

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat different quote has been attributed to Einstein: http://izquotes.com/quote/226612

Comment: That sounds a little different to me.

Comment: ... and also reminiscent of the un-snarky half of the joke that
**Tom Goodwillie** was reminded of.

Comment: this is Einsteins's quote in context: Einstein came to Princeton University in 1935 and was asked what he would require for his study. He replied: "A desk, some pads and a pencil, and a large wastebasket to hold all of my mistakes."

Comment: Something tells me there wasn't a lot of mathematical gold in Einstein's wastebasket.

Comment: The quote as cited by @CarloBeenakker is not to be trusted:  Einstein mostly wrote in ink.  I wouldn't trust the quote in the answer either.  See some images of his writing, the references to ink in his letters, and his gift to Ehrenfest of a pen that he used. http://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/history/Einstein_archive/, http://www.google.com/search?q=ink+site%3Aalberteinstein.info, http://musingsonmath.com/2011/03/14/has-anyone-seen-einsteins-pen/

Comment: A quick google search shows the Einstein quote all over the place, as if in an echo chamber. One wonders where it comes from originally; it could easily be a version of something Einstein said to Flexner which was later recalled by Flexner but with a slight inaccuracy.