# Authorship and the exact wording of a quote about mathematics

Tags: soft-question

This has been troubling me for a few days now and I just can't seem to bring Google to reveal the truth. Which brings me here despite the risk of this question being closed as off-topic.

A few years back, I recall reading of a more or less well-known mathematician being quoted along the lines of "every mathematical result is obvious, you just have to look at it the right way". Does anyone, by any chance, know who these words belong to and what the exact wording was?

(At first I was pretty sure that the quote was in Russian and belonged to Ernest Vinberg but now I just don't know anymore.)

Comment: reminds me of related words of Gromov, e.g., as quoted here: https://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/gromov-why-we-dont-explain-things/

Comment: Are you thinking of this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes/7342#7342

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, I don't think so. Of course, many mathematicians are likely to have said something to a similar effect, which lowers my chances of finding that specific quote. But thank you anyway, this quote (as well as Gromov's one above) seems to actually be more interesting than the one I am looking for.

Comment: And yes, more related quotes are very welcome!

Comment: "Obvious is the most dangerous word in mathematics." (E.T. Bell)